# Multi-table inheritance in the admin view

Tags: django

I have the following two models (multi-table inheritance):

```
class Funnies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class FunniesProfile(Funnies):    
    body = models.TextField()
```

I register both using the admin.site.register(). When I want to add a new "Funnies" entry I get the "title" field only. However, I would also like to get the field for the "body" so when an admin creates a new `Funnies` entry he will have the option to add a `FunniesProfile` entry that will automatically get the ptr_id of the `Funnies` entry. How can I do that?

Meir

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use this instead:

models.py:

```
class Funnies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class FunniesProfile(models.Model):    
    funnies = models.OneToOneField(Funnies)
    body = models.TextField()
```

admin.py:

```
class FunniesProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = FunniesProfile

class FunniesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        FunniesProfileInline,
    ]    
site.register(Funnies, FunniesAdmin)
```

Comment: Why the change in the models.py? Subclassing the Funnies model does the exact same thing, does it not?